# Docker complains "Address already in use" after docker restart command

Tags: docker

I am having a weird issue with my docker container. Everything works fine when dockers daemon starts up for the first time, but when docker is asked to restart a container, it will complain about address already used, despite the container was just running a second ago. This container will not start.

```
root@server:~# docker restart pihole
Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container pihole: Address already in use
```

Container is created from a following docker-compose. I do want to host DNS there, so I hardcode the IP addresses the network interface should receive.

```
version: "2"

services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    environment:
      TZ: 'Europe/Berlin'
      WEBPASSWORD: '**********'
      ServerIP: '192.168.178.16'
    volumes:
      - 'config:/etc/pihole'
      - 'dnsmasq:/etc/dnsmasq.d'
    networks:
      macvlan:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.178.16
        ipv6_address: fe80::10
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN 
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  macvlan:
    external:
      name: macvlan-bond0

volumes:
  config:
  dnsmasq:
```

Network macvlan-bond0 is a bulk standard macvlan network, with IPv4 subnet and gateway matching what DHCP would hand out, but with distint IPRange to avoid IP conflicts between containers and full blown hosts on that network.

```
root@server:~# docker network inspect macvlan-bond0
[
    {
        "Name": "macvlan-bond0",
        "Id": "322a33ac3db4dcaa286f1ca0369b1a50aac36c09a13ed7768d580daadb07db2b",
        "Created": "2022-08-30T11:16:30.144206169+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "macvlan",
        "EnableIPv6": true,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.178.0/24",
                    "IPRange": "192.168.178.32/28",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.178.1"
                },
                {
                    "Subnet": "fe80::/64",
                    "Gateway": "fe80::1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "7f71c160e8bd6d163f8fdc888c6a1355bbdd3bfab5e97d69b945c652b0d9c0e3": {
                "Name": "hass",
                "EndpointID": "8e2e911902caa928dfd5be8d476ca22bd65a3c92e2c1583893b7c9259c2224d1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:b2:11",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.178.17/24",
                "IPv6Address": "fe80::2/64"
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "parent": "bond0"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

The only way to start it up again is to remove the network, recreate it and attach the containers to it again. Or completely restart docker daemon. Both are not ideal as you can imagine.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Running following docker build, on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS:

```
root@server:~# docker --version
Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant here but these issues can popup if the TCP socket hasn't been fully closed yet (the TIME_WAIT socket state). See also SO_REUSEADDR option - this is a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/how-do-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-differ

Answer (score 0):

Check who is using same address/port

```
netstat -anlop|grep <address/port>
```

Remove container/process

```
docker rm docker_name
or
kill -9 <pid>
```

One you ensure address/port is free to use retry.

Comment: Nobody is using this address; it was used by the container being restarted. 

Port is not really relevant here, as it is `macvlan` network.